# Most efficient way to build range from range based on content (e.g. formula)

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the most efficient way with google script to build a range (newRange) from another range (baseRange) based on some criteria (e.g. the formula contains 'factorA') in the cells.

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActive();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const maxColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  baseRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxColumn, lastRow);
  criteria = "factorA";

...

};
```

The objective is to build newRange from baseRange with only those cells containing 'factorA' in the formula.

What is the efficient way of doing this without looping to death if the sheet is large?

I was unable to figure out better alternatives, but got this working:

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActive();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const maxColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  baseRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxColumn, lastRow);
  criteria = "factorA";

  for( var i = 0; i < baseRange.getLastRow(); i++){
    for( var j = 0; j < baseRange.getLastColumn(); j++){    
      var notation = baseRange.getCell(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation();
      var origFormula = baseRange.getCell(i+1,j+1).getFormula();      
      if(origFormula.toString().indexOf(prefixString) > -1){

        do a bunch of things with criteria to determine modifiedFormula

        var cell = baseRange.getCell(i+1,j+1);
        cell.setFormula(modifiedFormula);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

but is - as I feared - slow!

Is there a better (=faster) way?

Comment: So you would like to evaluate the content of each cell to decide either it shall be included in the new range? What about the gaps due to cells that shall not be included? Shall they have an empty vlaue in the new range or would you like to reduce your range size (be aware that the range needs to be rectangular and have the same number of cells in each row).?

Comment: The new range must include only those cells which fulfill the criteria (it must be smaller). Consequently the desired result will (most likely) NOT be rectangular.

Comment: In this case it will not be a range as per Apps Script definition and you will not able to transfer it onto a sheet (unless you fill the gaps with empty spaces). What is possible is to retrieve a 2-D array with the contents that meet the criteria, but you will no able to assign this array back to the sheet. Is retrieving a non-rectangular 2-D array what you would like to do?

Comment: If I understand you correctly the option I have then is to have an array of ranges (=those ranges fulfilling the criteria), right? Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: And array of ranges might better be described as a rangelist

Comment: My solution works, but is slow. Can it be made faster?